# Serializable Class serializes to Xml, but the same Xml won't deserialize

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, invalidoperationexception

We return instances of the class `AuthenticateUserOutput` from a WCF web service.

So we have this method:

`public override AuthenticateUserOutput AuthenticateUser(AuthenticateUserInput AuthenticateUserInput)`

AuthenicateUserOutput is auto generated:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.5420")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="xxxx")]
public partial class AuthenticateUserOutput : WS2MethodOutput
{

    private bool authenticationResultField;

    private UserContext userContextField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool AuthenticationResult
    {
        get
        {
            return this.authenticationResultField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.authenticationResultField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public UserContext UserContext
    {
        get
        {
            return this.userContextField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.userContextField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

We need to be able to de serialize as `AuthenticateUserOutput`, but it's not working.

As a test, I instantiated an `AuthenticateUserOutput`, serialized it and tried to de-serialize it.

It fails with InvalidOperationException.

Here's the serialized Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<AuthenticateUserOutput xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="xxxx">
  <Response xmlns="xxxx">
    <IsValid>true</IsValid>
    <Success>true</Success>
  </Response>
  <AuthenticationResult xmlns="xxxx">true</AuthenticationResult>
  <UserContext xmlns="xxxx">
  </UserContext>
</AuthenticateUserOutput>
```

Here's the serialization and de-serialization code:

```
    public static string ToXml(this object input)
    {
        string output;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(input.GetType());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, input);
        }
        output = sb.ToString();
        return output;
    }
```

And:

```
    public static T FromXml<T>(this string input)
    {
        T output;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        output = (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(input));

        return output;
    }
```

The exact details of the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message="<AuthenticateUserOutput xmlns='xxxx'> was not expected."
  Source="qkxd8dd-"
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderAuthenticateUserOutput.Read31_AuthenticateUserOutput()
  InnerException:
```

So it can't de-serialize it's own serialized Xml.

Can anybody see why?

Thanks,

J1M.

**UPDATE**: Here is the test code:

```
        AuthenticateUserOutput test = new AuthenticateUserOutput();

        test.AuthenticationResult = true;
        test.Response = new ResponseType();
        test.Response.Exception = null;
        test.Response.IsValid = true;
        test.Response.Success = true;
        test.Response.ValidationErrors = null;
        test.UserContext = new UserContext();

        string serializedXml = test.ToXml();

        AuthenticateUserOutput deserializedString = serializedXml.FromXml<AuthenticateUserOutput>();
```

**UPDATE2**: Deserializer works thanks to Mark Gravell

[OK, I forgot I'd added this to get the namespaces to come out correctly when de-serializing:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242038/adding-root-xmlns-using-xmlserializer-with-wcf-soap)

```
public partial class WS2MethodInput
{
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces _xmlns;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for WS2MethodInput that sets up default namespaces
    /// </summary>
    public WS2MethodInput()
    {
        _xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        _xmlns.Add("", "xxxx");
    }
}
```

With this, the serialized Xml is as it was at the top of this message.
Without it, the de-serializer works but AuthenticateUserOutput is missing a namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<AuthenticateUserOutput xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="xxxx">
  <Response xmlns="xxxx">
    <IsValid>true</IsValid>
    <Success>true</Success>
  </Response>
  <AuthenticationResult xmlns="xxxx">true</AuthenticationResult>
  <UserContext xmlns="xxxx">
  </UserContext>
</AuthenticateUserOutput>
```

Note the `xmlns="xxxx"` at the end of `AuthenticateUserOutput`

Problem is, now I can't use that Xml with our other code without either:

1) Loading it into an XDocument and adding the namespace and removing it when I need to de-serialize it
2) Doing the same with string replace of regex or something

Neither of which I really like. In fact that's horrible! 8X

Comment: what is the `T` to `FromXml`, and what is the `GetType()` of the original object? are they the same?

Comment: I'll add the test code, T is AuthenticateUserOutput. I'll be doing this for A LOT of methods so I started by writing To/From Xml extensions

Comment: Oh and yes, typeof(T) == input.GetType()

Comment: your test code basically works for me; I had to tweak it a bit to get it to compile though (adding some classes, removing Response)

Comment: Thanks, that's allowed me to get mine working. I figured out why and I shall add more to the post. However the problem is cause by a solution to a different problem I added and forgot to post. But, if I remove that solution, the other problem comes back. Bear with me.

Comment: I'm going to close this question and start a different one, as I now need to find a proper way to solve the other problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was setting the XmlSerializerNamespaces to force xmlns on the root element.

Take that away and it works.

However, now I can't use the serialized Xml anywhere else because it's missing a namespace.

I will start a new question that is focused on that.

Thanks,

J1M.

**UPDATE:**

OK, I figured it out so I'm not going to write a new question.

Given the following XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:www-test-com:testservice" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:www-test-com:testservice" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="AuthenticateUserInput">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Used to provide user credentials to the AuthenticateUser method</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Username" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Method" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

svcutil generates something like this, although I imagine there are lots of tools that spit out something similar for that XSD:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:www-test-com:testservice")]
public class AuthenticateUserInput
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
}
```

Now, using the "default" `XmlSerializer` code:

```
    static string ToXml(object input)
    {
        string output;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(input.GetType());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(xw, input);
        }
        output = sb.ToString();
        return output;
    }
```

You get the following Xml:

```
<AuthenticateUserInput xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Username xmlns="urn:www-test-com:testservice">sa</Username>
    <Password xmlns="urn:www-test-com:testservice">Password1</Password>
    <Method xmlns="urn:www-test-com:testservice">Plain</Method>
</AuthenticateUserInput>
```

Which does NOT conform to the schema (validation fails, which is what is killing us at the moment)

OK, so, I found a reference to changing `[XmlType]` to `[XmlRoot]` and a cursory test worked, if I change the generated class I now get the following conformant Xml:

```
<AuthenticateUserInput xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:www-test-com:testservice">
    <Username>sa</Username>
    <Password>Password1</Password>
    <Method>Plain</Method>
</AuthenticateUserInput>
```

But I don't want to hand change all the auto generated classes. So after some time I found the following solution:

```
    static string ToXml(object input)
    {
        string output;

        XmlSerializer serializer = CreateSerializer(input.GetType());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Encoding =  Encoding.UTF8, Indent = true };

        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(xw, input);
        }
        output = sb.ToString();
        return output;
    }

    static T FromXml<T>(string input)
    {
        T output;

        XmlSerializer serializer = CreateSerializer(typeof(T));

        output = (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(input));

        return output;
    }

    private static XmlSerializer CreateSerializer(Type incomingType)
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes newAttributes = new XmlAttributes();

        newAttributes.XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        newAttributes.XmlRoot.Namespace = ((XmlTypeAttribute)incomingType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlTypeAttribute), true)[0]).Namespace;
        attrOverrides.Add(incomingType, newAttributes);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(incomingType, attrOverrides);
        return serializer;
    }
```

As you can see, rather than just using the default constructor for XmlSerializer, you can create an `XmlAttributeOverrides` and add to it one `XmlAttributes` on which you instantiate the `XmlRoot` attribute.
In order to make this nice and generic, it hoovers the Namespace out of the incoming type with `((XmlTypeAttribute)incomingType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlTypeAttribute), true)[0]).Namespace`, which fails if the type doesn't have that attribute so this solution needs more work but you get the general idea.

Regards,

`J1M`